# Documenting API which may be changed

Tags: java, api, javadoc

I am working on a Java project which makes heavy use of JavaDoc and produces an open API. We would like some way of documenting when an API is likely to change. Is there a precedent for this out there?

Comment: If an API changes, the precedent is to deprecate the old version, but keep it for legacy code.  Then add the new version in parallel (maybe adding something like Java's `@since` annotation to indicate which version of your library first introduced the API).  It's up to you to determine how long to keep the deprecated version.  I'm sorry that I'm not aware of a way to flag an API that may change in the *future*, only of mechanisms used to let people know that an API available i the past has changed.

Comment: This is to be used when a feature is introduced into the API, but is not in a stable state. It may be updated in the next few releases before it is finalized. This will allow the community to speak into the finally look of the API.

Comment: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/README.md might be relevant.

Comment: If you anticipate a lot of changes, call your project an alpha version until the API has stabilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just indicate it in the javadoc. For example, the javadoc of [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) (and many other Swing components):

> **Warning**: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with
>   future Swing releases. The current serialization support is
>   appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running
>   the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of
>   all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see
>   XMLEncoder.

Such an information is part of the class contract, so javadoc is the place to document it.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd like to quote Joshua Bloch, from his talk [How to Design a Good API & Why it Matters](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design):

> When in doubt, leave it out!

You can always add new things to an API later, but you can never change remove a method that has been there, because people will be *using* this exact method, and won't be pleased when it's suddenly no longer there.

---

Now, in reality, APIs **do** change. You can reduce the hassle for users of this API by not simply changing the API from one version to the next, but at least establish a graceful *deprecation model*. When a method is about to be changed or removed, it should be marked as `@Deprecated` in one version, together with a hint about how it is supposed to be "emulated" with the new API, and removed in a subsequent version, so that users may have time to adapt.

---

Finally, regarding your actual question:

The JavaDocs should be the first place to write notices like this. Of course, there are enough developers out there who don't read the docs, but a clear **WARNING** in the JavaDoc is at least something that you can refer to when the complaints drop in after you published the changes ;-)

Another option is to use annotations. The Guava people added [the @Beta annotation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html):

> Signifies that a public API (public class, method or field) is subject to incompatible changes, or even removal, in a future release. An API bearing this annotation is exempt from any compatibility guarantees made by its containing library. Note that the presence of this annotation implies nothing about the quality or performance of the API in question, only the fact that it is not "API-frozen."
>
> It is generally safe for applications to depend on beta APIs, at the cost of some extra work during upgrades. However it is generally inadvisable for libraries (which get included on users' CLASSPATHs, outside the library developers' control) to do so.

which might come in handy here, if it suits your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

You can change APIs in ways that are *compatible* or *incompatible* with existing code.

Public APIs ideally change only in ways that are compatible with existing code. Sometimes exceptions need to be made.

**If you can predict in advance that an API is subject to incompatible changes, consider making it a private API, rather than simply marking it in JavaDoc.**

Private APIs can be changed in incompatible ways. Precedents for marking private APIs include:

- Use access control to make APIs non-public.
- Place the code in a package that includes a term indicating that it is not intended for public usage, such as `internal` or `impl`. For example, the Eclipse platform has many packages that include the term `internal`.

You can also mark APIs that are *not* likely to change. Interfaces accessible to third parties are typically not expected to change at all prior to Java 8. (After Java 8, methods can be added to interfaces without breaking existing code, via default methods.)